# Mac claims to have connected to wireless network, but hasn't

Tags: macos, wireless-networking

I am attempting to connect a new mac OSX 10.6.5 laptop to a wireless network (I am a windows expert but a mac novice). It used to connect without problem to the network when I had the security set to "64 bit wep". Now I have changed the security on my belkin router to "WPA-PSK (no server)". I have two PC's and an old mac connecting via the new security setting without problem. Now I have the problem that on the new mac, the wireless icon is indicating a good connection (5 dark bars). Also the network name has a tick next to it on the wireless drop down menu. But I can not view any websites. I can not even connect to the router by typing 192.168.2.1 into a browser address bar. Any ideas where I went wrong?

Comment: Do you have a DHCP server on the network? What is the IP address of the Mac (`ifconfig`, then look for `en1` in Terminal, or check the `TCP/IP` tab under `Advanced...` in `Network` in `System Preferences`)? Do the Windows machine have manually assigned IP addresses? Does your accept point have a client whitelist of some sort, e.g. for DHCP clients? Do you have enough unused DHCP addresses to be able to assign one to your Mac?

Answer (score 0):

In Network Utility try to ping google.com If that fails, try to ping 8.8.8.8 If that succeeds, you need to check your DNS settings.
Check System Preferences - Network - Airport - Advanced (button near bottom right of window) - DNS

Comment: "I can not even connect to the router by typing 192.168.2.1 into a browser address bar" -- so it's not (only) a DNS issue.

Answer (score 0):

You had good signal reception and ancient weak WEP encryption.
You changed to WPA encryption. Ofc. this did not change signal strength.

But OSX does not notice the change and hence fails to communicate (which results in no DHCP lease etc etc). So your question probably is "How can I force OSX to rescan for wireless networks or how can I flush the old information so I can reconfigure?"

I do not know how to do the last in OSX, but you could always change the SSID of the WAP. Then all devices will treat it as a new access point.